# Define an interval while entering values in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a table as follows:

```
CREATE table screening
(
  screening_id NUMBER(6,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  plan_id NUMBER(4,0),
  theatre_id NUMBER(1,0),
  screening_date DATE,
  screening_start_hh24 NUMBER(2,0) CHECK(screening_start_hh24 BETWEEN 9 AND 22),
  screening_start_mm60 NUMBER(2,0) CHECK(screening_start_mm60 BETWEEN 0 AND 59),
  CONSTRAINT fk_plan_id FOREIGN KEY(plan_id)
    REFERENCES screening_plan(plan_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_theatre_id_screening FOREIGN KEY(theatre_id)
    REFERENCES theatre(theatre_id)
)
```

'screening_start_hh24' is for start time in hour and 'screening_start_mm60' is for start time in minutes.
What should I do to add a break of at least 30mins between two consecutive screenings in the same theatre? I am using oracle.

Comment: That's generally not something that you would define in declarative constraints.  That's normally a business rule that you would implement in the stored procedure that inserts data into this table.  Also, since `screening_date` is a `date`, it will inherently have a day and a time.  It makes no sense to split out the time into two additional columns, presumably setting the time on `screening_date` to midnight rather than just setting `screening_date` correctly.

Comment: I understand the fact that screening_date will have the time as well. Rather than extracting the time from date will which use more CPU time, it will be better to add two columns. Besides stored procedure, is there no other way to define it will creating the table?

Comment: Storing the time separately violates basically every rule of normalization.  I assume that you've done benchmarking that shows that your application's bottleneck is really extracting the time from a `date` column and that this denormalization really eliminates that bottleneck.  There is no way to create a constraint that crosses rows.  You could create an `on commit` materialized view that stores the next screening date in the same row and put a constraint on that materialized view if you're really determined.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure (in or out of a package) to add screenings and implement the logic in that:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE screening_seq;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE screening_pkg AS
  PROCEDURE addScreening(
    i_plan_id IN  screening.plan_id%TYPE,
    i_theatre_id IN  screening.theatre_id%TYPE,
    i_start   IN  screening.screening_date%TYPE,
    o_error   OUT VARCHAR2
  );
END screening_pkg;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY screening_pkg AS
  PROCEDURE addScreening(
    i_plan_id    IN  screening.plan_id%TYPE,
    i_theatre_id IN  screening.theatre_id%TYPE,
    i_start      IN  screening.screening_date%TYPE,
    o_error      OUT VARCHAR2
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE
      v_exists NUMBER(1,0);
    BEGIN
      SELECT 1
      INTO   v_exists
      FROM   screening
      WHERE  theatre_id = i_theatre_id
      AND    screening_date BETWEEN i_start - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
                            AND     i_start + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE;

      o_error := 'Screening exists within 30 minutes.';
      RETURN;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        NULL;
    END;

    INSERT INTO screening (
      screening_id,
      plan_id,
      theatre_id,
      screening_date,
      screening_start_hh24,
      screening_start_mm60
    ) VALUES (
      screening_seq.NEXTVAL,
      i_plan_id,
      i_theatre_id,
      i_start,
      TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( i_start, 'HH24' ) ),
      TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( i_start, 'MI' ) )
    );
  END addScreening;
END screening_pkg;
/
```

Also, you don't need the hours and minutes columns - you can just use the date column.